# Linq match list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to compare values ​​using linq.

Data option : A, B, C, D

(original)My data : A, B, C

(modify)My data : B, D

my data : A - Delete, B - not change, C - Delete, D - Add

Linq expressions how to express it?

Data type is List

Comment: I have no idea what you're writing about. Could you explain it again, much more clear?

Comment: Please could you provide code

Comment: What is the use of `Data option`?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may want the [LINQ set operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx):

```
var added = modified.Except(original);
var deleted = original.Except(modified);
var unchanged = modified.Intersect(original);
```

That's assuming you don't care about *ordering*, of course. There are no doubt more efficient ways of finding these - but unless you actually *need* to worry about performance, I'd use this as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you! Good Link to article.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var option =   new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
var original = new[] {"A", "B", "C"};
var modify =   new[] {"B", "D"};

var deleted = original.Except(modify);        // A, C
var added   = modify.Except(original);        // D
var not_changed = modify.Intersect(original); // B
```